# Syslog file missing 22.04

Tags: syslog

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 ARM version on my M2 MacBook Air using Parallels Desktop. I did this because I am taking the Google IT Support certificate through Coursera and wanted access to Linux for practise and learning. I have no previous experience with Linux other than through Coursera. One of my Coursera videos demonstrated viewing the "syslog" file found in the /var/log directory. However, no such "syslog" file exists in the /var/log directory in my installation. I note that the Google course is using an older version of Ubuntu. Should the "syslog" file exist in the var/log file in my installation and if so, does anyone know why it isn't there? [Screenshot of ls /var/log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gItEY.png)

Answer (score 0):

In attempting to fix another problem (unable to view "man" pages for commands), I discovered that Parallels Desktop installs a "minimized" version of Ubuntu. I ran the "sudo unminimize" command per a helpful post in the Parallels Desktop community and voila! - a bunch of additional logs including the "syslog" are now in my /var/log directory.